# excel 2016, populating 'summary' with drop down items from other cells in the sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple rows with drop down lists.  When an abnormal value is used from the dropdown items (red) I want them to auto populate the "DIAGNOSTIC TESTING" cell.  Ideally as a list or separated by commas.

Comment: Tried to add screen shot but it did not show in pos

Comment: Please retry posting the screenshot, there's not enough information here to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate post of https://superuser.com/questions/1397178/excel-2016-multiple-rows-with-drop-down-lists-when-item-chosen-it-also-appears